# How to migrate LDAP to other computer

Tags: ldap, openldap, migration

How can I migrate LDAP from one computer to other..??

I tried using:

```
slapcat -n 0 -l (config file location)
```

and

```
slapcat -n 1 -l (database backup ldif path)
```

It gives this error:

```
$ slapcat -d -1 -l slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif 
5acd24a4 slapcat init: initiated tool.
5acd24a4 slap_sasl_init: initialized!
5acd24a4 backend_startup_one: starting "cn=config"
5acd24a4 ldif_read_file: read entry file without checksum: "/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif"
5acd24a4 => str2entry: ""
5acd24a4 str2entry: entry -1 has no dn
5acd24a4 send_ldap_result: conn=-1 op=0 p=0
5acd24a4 send_ldap_result: err=80 matched="" text="internal error (cannot parse some entry file)"
slapcat: bad configuration file!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` is for output, not the location of the config.

You probably wanted something more akin to `slapcat -n 0 -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/ -l ~/slapdconfig.ldif`.

At this point you may have destroyed your config (or at least the `cn=config` part of it. Hopefully you have a backup. If not, you may be able to extract it from the running server if you have a dn with appropriate access to `cn=config`. Be sure to get both the `*` and `+` attribute sets.

Comment: Your are right, I had to restore my ldap files. Thanks a lot.